# hotel reservation validation through a searchform, ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, search

i want to develop a hotel reservationsystem as a project for my university.

i have a table for rooms, reservations and customers. the reservationtable has the following fields:room_id , customer_id , arrival, departure .

i have a searchform where you can choose which kind of room you want to reserve, the arrival and departure date. after you fill in the form, an available room should be displayed.

but i have to validate if a room is really available during the dates. does anyone has an idea in which model the validation should happen, because i think i have to acces several models, i need the roomtype from the room model and the arrival and departure dates from the reservations model.

thanks folks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do a couple of things. One, is to put your reservation logic outside of a single model but make like a `Service` or `Manager` object which takes all the necessary objects as input and then wraps all your business logic together.

```
class RoomNotAvailableException < StandardError; end

class ReservationService
  def initialize(room, customer, arrival, departure)
    @room = room
    @customer = customer
    @arrival = arrival
    @departure = departure
  end

  def reserve!
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      if room_available?
        Reservation.create(:room => @room, :customer => @customer, :arrival => @arrival, :departure => @departure)
      else
        raise RoomNotAvailableException
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def room_available?
    Reservation.where(:room_id => @room.id, :arrival => @arrival, :departure => @departure).exists?
  end

end
```

Use it in a controller like

```
def create
  # get the objects from params or whatever
  service = ReservationService.new(room, customer, arrival, departure)
  begin
    service.reserve!
    flash[:notice] = "You are booked!" 
    redirect_to('somewhere')
  rescue RoomNotAvailableException => ex
    # whatever you need to do here..
  end
end
```

Two, if you're using Postgres you can use `CHECK CONSTRAINTS` to do the checking for you. To ensure that no two intervals overlap. You'll have to google around but the gist can be found in some Postgres threads:

http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20050520162508.GA87868@mighty.grot.org

Comment: ok thanks, i ll try that.It's maybe a pretty stupid question, but what exactly do you mean when you propose a service or manager object? where do i have to impelement that?

Comment: @AndyB Service/Manager/etc .. thats just a naming convention, it doesnt matter what you call it. Conceptually its just a place where you encapsulate your business logic that crosses multiple models / pieces of domain logic. In addition its an encapsulation that you can re-use. Maybe you have an API that allows for reservations in addition to your web form - in such a case you'd want to re-use the same service object. Thus you remove any notion of the actual HTTP layer and all it knows how to do is your actual business logic. make sense?

Comment: In terms of location on disk, somewhere that is appropriate for you. Maybe in `lib` or `app/services/reservation_service.rb`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**None of them.**

Often it is best to create a separate controller that does not represent a resource when dealing with multiple resources. This sounds like one of those situations.